# Grub doesn't detect Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

As you can guess from the title, I can't access Windows from grub (dual boot). I have tried many different things I saw on many different websites, but none seem to work.

The problem is some might have worked had my Ubuntu been in a better state : I get a black screen after the Ubuntu logo, and even though I can get ctrl alt F#, it seems I also have issues with both sudo and pkexec (some permission stuff that an internet "solution" made worse).

I tried boot-repair on a live CD which didn't change my Windows situation.
Can anyone help me get Windows back ? (I know my Ubuntu is a mess, I'll reinstall it later)

PS : I have almost no experience with partitions or even Ubuntu commands although I do my best

**EDIT** 
I have somehow solved my problem (actually I just dodged it, nothing is solved)
I launched boot-repair from my live CD and selected MBR rather than Grub. Grub never found a Windows partition (that I could see at least), but MBR launches Windows normally.

Comment: Can you describe the issues you have with `sudo`?  Can you give the specific error message?  For instance, what do you get when you type `sudo ls /`?

Comment: @L. D. JamesThanks for the quick answer ! I get `sudo: etc/sudoers is world writable`
`sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting`
`sudo: unable to initialize policy again`

Comment: The only time something like that happened to me was when Intel RST (Rapid storage Technology) was turned on in BIOS.

Comment: What brand/model system? Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Missing from grub**

To resolve the issue with Grub detecting Windows, you would have to install and update grub.  This can be done from the live CD.

Run these commands one by one:

```
1) sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt # (If your Linux were on a different partition substitute /sda1 for the partition of your Linux install.)
2) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
3) sudo chroot /mnt
4) update-grub
5) grub-install /dev/sda # (/dev/sda is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda or /dev/sdb ... etc.)
    update-grub
```

**The `sudo` issue**

There might be other problems, but you might first check the integrity of the `/etc/sudoer` file.  You can do this from the Live disk by first copying your current file to a backup file (sudoer.bak) and copying the distribution sudoer from the Live media to your hard drives sudoer file.

exiting out of the `chroot` with the command `exit` if you are still in it.  With your hard drive mounted as /mnt perform these steps:

```
$ cd /mnt/etc
$ sudo cp sudoer sudoer.bak
$ cp /etc/sudoer sudoer
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed instructions !
Unfortunately it didn't work. I don't have a live CD where I am right now so I used the recovery mode to get a root terminal and try to fix the Windows Missing problem with your instructions.

It all went smoothly but didn't solve the problem, Windows still doesn't show up.
I guess there is something wrong with my partitions, do you need me to write what `fdisk -l` shows ?